# Excel Formula to find Matched value within multiple column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a dataset such as below in Excel:

| Tel | Mob | Off | Checking |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 45345 | 9473 | 5356 | Match |
| 675673 | 35232 | 786547 | No match |
| 54657 | 1353 | 42545 | No match |
| 534734 | 534734 | 546 | No match |
| 24566 | 5456 | 4525 | No match |
| 45345 | 1343 | 26436 | Match |

Then, I would like to check whether the Tel column has matched with any of the Tel, Mob and Off column. However, if the match is in the same row, then it's still considered unmatched. The Checking column is the exactly output that I want.

I have try using this simple formula, however, it's still didn't get the output as I wanted.

```
IF((COUNTIF($A$2:$A$7,A2) + COUNTIF($B$2:$B$7,A2) + COUNTIF($C$2:$C$7,A2))<2,"No match","Match")
```

Is there any other formula in Excel that could cater this other than using Kutools or VBA?

Comment: Why has the last row "No match"? It's the pendant to the first row ...

Comment: @Ike yup should be match as well. has been corrected

Comment: What if the match is on the same row for a given value of Tel col, but also in other column on a different row? How would be that situation handled? For example the following `2x3` array `{1,0,1};{0,2,1}`. On the first row `1` has a match on the same row (no Match), but on the second row there a match to `1` a valid one. So the result would be uncertain. It is not clear this statement to me for all possible scenarios: *"if the match is in the same row, then it's still considered unmatched"*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one is a bit shorter :-)

`=IF(COUNTIF($A$2:$C$7,A2) - COUNTIF(A2:C2,A2) > 0,"Match","No match")`

It first counts the all occurences of `Tel` in the whole matrix and then removes the ones from the same row (e.g. 534734). If the result is > 0 then there are matches.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively try `MMULT()`:

```
=IF(SUM(N(MMULT(N(A$2:C$7=A2),{1;1;1})>0))>1,"","No ")&"Match"
```

Answer (score 2):

You may try this as well.

[image]

• Formula used in cell `D2`

```
=IF(SUM(N(A$2:C$7=A2))>SUM(N(A2:C2=A2)),"Match","No Match")
```

Answer (score 2):

Lets give a try to an array version in `F2` (this is an extension of @Ike's answer)

```
=LET(cntRange, COUNTIF(A2:C7,A2:A7), 
  cntRow,BYROW(--(A2:C7=A2:A7), LAMBDA(row, SUM(row))),
  IF((cntRange - cntRow) > 0, "Match", "No Match"))
```

or without `LET`:

```
=IF((COUNTIF(A2:C7,A2:A7) - 
  BYROW(--(A2:C7=A2:A7),LAMBDA(row, SUM(row)))) > 0, "Match", "Not Match")
```

[image: sample excel file]

The trick here is to emulate `COUNTIF` with `--(A2:C7=A2:A7)` it returns a `6x3` matrix and per row as many `1`s as repetition we have of each cell of `A2:A7`, then `SUM(row)` does the magic of the count.

Comment: First I thought this is cool - but it is not the correct solution: if you put e.g. 675673 in B4, row 3 should give a match ...

Comment: Thanks, @Ike, you were correct. I updated my answer. Now it works for the failed case. For the array version, I ended up in a variant of your solution. I gave you credit. To build the recurrence per row for calculating the count, I had to emulate it via `SUM` of `1`s.

Comment: As always: there are several solutions :-)

Answer (score 0):

I got this formula, Not sure if there is any direct way though;

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(A2:C2,A2)>1,"No Match",IF(OR(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$7,A2)>1,COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$7,A2)>0,COUNTIFS($C$2:$C$7,A2)>0),"Match","No Match"))
```

Hope this Helps...